# Cancan + Devise rescue_from not catching exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I am implementing Devise and Cancan for user authentication and permissions. Everything works great so far except I am not able to redirect users to the login page when they are not allowed to access a specific feature.

My test is:

```
feature 'A signed in user' do
  before(:each) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit "/login"
    fill_in "user_email", :with => user.email
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "ilovebananas"
    click_button "Sign in"
  end

  scenario 'should not have access to admin dashboard' do
    visit '/admin'
    page.should have_content 'Log in'
  end
end
```

And I get the following failure:

```
Failures:
      1) A signed in user should not have access to admin dashboard
         Failure/Error: visit '/admin'
         CanCan::AccessDenied:
         You are not authorized to access this page.
```

To be clear, all my permission management works as expected so far, except the redirection to login page.

---

### Here is how things are set up:

**ApplicationController:**

```
check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller? # Cancan

rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to login_path, alert: exception.message
end
```

**UsersController**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource         # Cancan
  def queue  
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

**AdminsController**

```
class AdminController < ActionController::Base
  authorize_resource :class => false # Cancan, used because AdminController doesn't have an associated model
  ...
end
```

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user, not logged in
    can :queue, User

    if user.has_permission? :super_admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_permission? :network_admin

    end      
  end
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I face the same error for `rails_admin` on `/admin`, though I added `rescue_from` in my `application_controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Admins Controller was not < ApplicationController, so it did not load the ApplicationController rescue_from method.

Making the change solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must pass class name as string. try quoting it. or try

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied , :with => :login_page
private
def login_page
   redirect_to login_path
end
```

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work either. How is this different from what I already have in my ApplicationController?

Comment: try like `rescue_from 'CanCan::AccessDenied'`  (quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You should to add "controller.authorize_resource" to admin/register.if abilities without conditions.

```
controller.authorize_resource
```

Example: can :manage, :all

If conditions are,

```
controller do
  load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:update,:index, :show, :edit]
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.accessible_by(current_ability)
  end
end
```

Example: can :manage, Master::Country, :organization_branch_id => each_branch.id

i hope it help you

Comment: I already have this in my code (see edit in my question). Any other idea?